# How to clean the buffer in c?

Tags: c, linux, bash, buffer

I'm doing a lot of iterations in order to simulate the `bash` command (Homework) .

The code works great , but the problem is that after a few iterations of inputs , the program 
starts to have some buffer problems . I suspect it has something to do with all the `\n` of `Enter` hits .

For example , the code starts like this :

```
#define BUFFER 4096
#define RUN_FOREVER 1
#define ERROR_SIGN -1
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int main(int argc , char * argv[] )
{
    char input[BUFFER];

    //Get always a command line from the user.
    while(RUN_FOREVER)

    {

        if (isatty(0))
        {
            // input is from terminal
            // need to put something here 
        }

        char **separatedFormAmpersand ;

        int ampersandsCtr = 0, k=0,r=0;
        char *stringBeforeAmpersand = NULL;

        printf("$ ");


        memset(input, '\0', BUFFER);

         char ch;

        scanf("%[^\n]",input);
        scanf("%c",&ch);

        if(0 == strcmp(input, "exit"))
            break;

        //Separate the command according to the "&".
        stringBeforeAmpersand = strtok( input, "&");
... // more code (quite a lot , frankly)
```

Now , if the user hits the following inputs :

```
ls Debug/ | grep r
ls >> file.jer & ls & ls & ls
ls >> file.jer
```

one after the other , then the code doesn't recognize the `ls` command when I hit input number `3` .

If I enter each input in a single run of the code , everything works perfectly .

Any ideas how to clean the buffer ? maybe `fflush` ?

Thanks!

Comment: Show the code where you declare `input`. And show all the allocations that you make. There's no evidence that you allocated any buffers.

Comment: It'd be nice to see the declarations of BUFFER and input.

Comment: I do not understand *what* the problem is, and what the answers are trying to achieve. I created a version of your code that compiles cleanly with GCC: http://pastebin.com/cNM6441f. It works fine. i.e. it recognizes the first "&" separated token properly.

Comment: Clearly, if you think there is a problem, you have missed out the bit of code that is relevant. Try to produce a version of your program that adheres to: http://sscce.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flushing stdout would clearly be a good thing to do before you can tell anything from your code.

I assume that your pair of `scanf` has the following goal : one will grab one line, and the second will "skip the \n" character. You could just use `getc()` for the later, btw. The wonder is whether scanf() itself will read the `\n` character for you.

In its GNU fashion, `scanf()` may prove superior to `fgets()` here, in that the `%a[...]` modifier can get you rid of "buffer size" limitations and lets the library `malloc()` a buffer of adequate size for you.

Ever thought about invoking your program with strace to track reading of the input ?

Answer (score 1):

To read a line of input, use this:

```
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
```

And check it's return value for failure. Do note that it will include the newline though, so you might want to add code to remove it.